# fatal: repository not found (git + http + nginx + fastcgi)

Tags: git, http, ubuntu, nginx, fastcgi

I am trying to serve git repositories using Nginx. I have the following configuration for Nginx server:

```
worker_processes  auto;

error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {

}


http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;


    log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    server {
        listen80;
        root  /home/path/to/repositories;
     
        location ~ \.git {

            auth_basic "Restricted";
            auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.gitpasswd;
                                    
            include fastcgi_params; 
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend;
            fastcgi_param GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /home/path/to/repositories;
            fastcgi_param GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL "";
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $uri;
            fastcgi_param REMOTE_USER $remote_user;
            client_max_body_size            0;

            fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket; 
        }

    }

}
```

But when i try to clone it in a folder with the following command:

```
git clone http://user:password@my-local-ip/repo-name.git folder-name
```

I get the following result:

```
Cloning into 'folder-name'...
fatal: repository 'http://my-local-ip/repo-name.git/' not found
```

But the repository is there! I can serve it through "dumb http" with:

```
location /repositories {
            root  /home/path/to;
        }
```

I've checked the error.log of nginx and when I try to clone with "smart HTTP" I get:

```
2022/12/05 17:09:22 [error] 79488#79488: *43 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Not a git repository: '/home/path/to/repositories/repo-name.git'" while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.1.13, server: , request: "GET /repo-name.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket:", host: "192.168.1.13"
```